# Issue with LEFT JOIN with Exists

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, where-clause, exists

I have two tables, Service and Site- they have a one-to-many relationship, with one row in Service potentially having multiple rows in Site.

I am fetching Site table where some Ids are used for more then once. Now I want to fetch all rows from Service for this Site.

```
SERVICE Table{id}
SITE Table{id,svcId(from SERVICE Table),siteid}

SELECT *
FROM SERVICE
WHERE EXISTS( 
    SELECT * FROM SITE WHERE (siteid='3' or siteid='4') AND id IN (
    SELECT id FROM SITE GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) > 1
))
```

The Select query inside exists fetch me all the rows with more than once with `siteid` 3 and 4 But the entire query is fetching me all the rows from `SERVICE TABLE`. I was Expecting only the rows with Matching id.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: How `service` table is related to `site` table ? The subquery is not correlated to the outer query by any column from the outer table, so it always gives either all or none rows from `service` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a condition `and s.id = st.svcId` with proper aliases inside exists .

```
SELECT *
FROM SERVICE s
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT *
  FROM SITE st
  WHERE (siteid='3'
  OR siteid    ='4')
  AND id      IN
    ( SELECT id FROM SITE GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) 
    and s.id = st.svcId
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the services that relate to BOTH siteid 3 AND 4 (i.e. the count of that service will be >1).

```
SELECT sv.*
FROM SERVICE sv
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
            svcId
      FROM SITE
      WHERE (siteid = '3' OR siteid = '4')
      GROUP BY
            svcId
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) si ON sv.id = si.svcId
```

Comment: somehow i always get an sql error on this saying "si.svcId" as invalid identifier even though the column exist in DB. not sure whats wrong.

Comment: does the subquery work by itself?       SELECT
            svcId
      FROM SITE
      WHERE (siteid = '3' OR siteid = '4')
      GROUP BY
            svcId
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: Then there is no apparent reason for the error unless you removed the subquery alias **si** which is shown in the answer.

Comment: Then there is no apparent reason for that error. I cant do anything further.